# Hiding Feedly categories

Tags: rss-reader, feedly, mute

How can I mute a category from my main feed?

I want to only see those feeds when I open the category in the side bar but I don't want them cluttering up my main feed.

Comment: There's a feature request which you could [vote](https://feedly.uservoice.com/forums/192636-suggestions/suggestions/4439278-give-us-an-option-to-mute-categories-time-saver-f) for.

Answer (score 4):

Feature to mute categories from the main feed doesn't exist ([vote here](https://feedly.uservoice.com/forums/192636-suggestions/suggestions/4439278-give-us-an-option-to-mute-categories-time-saver-f)).

Currently the only choice is to use '[Mute Filters](https://blog.feedly.com/mute-filters/)' to create a temporary mute for individual websites on all feeds. You can pause it at any time if you want to access the muted feed.

Please note, that this is a Feedly Pro feature.

1. Click on "Filters" on the left navigation bar.
2. Add a mute filter with keyword "site:mutedwebsite.com"

Then you can activate, and pause the filter as you wish.

[image]